# Twain driver concurrent requests

Tags: twain

It's possible to use one twain driver to manage concurrent request to two different multifunction printer?

I mean, if I have two MFPs , can I do two scan request in paralel using the same twain driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if your driver supports it.

From the [TWAIN Spec](http://www.twain.org/docs/530fe0da85f7511c510004ff/TWAIN-2.3-Spec.pdf) page 125:
If an application attempts to connect to a Source that only supports a single connection when the source is already opened, the Source should respond with TWRC_FAILURE and TWCC_MAXCONNECTIONS.

Also from the spec on page 212:
The Source is responsible for managing this, not the Source Manager (the Source Manager does not know in advance how many connections the Source will support).

I tested this with a Fujitsu fi-7260 scanner and got the TWCC_MAXCONNECTIONS error with Twacker:

[image: Screenshot of twacker select source dialog]

[image: Screenshot of twacker error]

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible. The reason being TWAIN just sits between the application and the images fed to it. 
Imagine a scenario something on the below lines:

1) User clicked on the scan button.
2) You initiate the network layer calls to start the scan job.
3) Now instead to one printer you start scan jobs on two printers from two threads.
4) Let's say each of those threads populate the raw BMP data to a single data structure that is shared.
5) Once both threads are complete iterate over that shared data structure to pass the images to the application via the XFERIMAGE call.

Basic idea is to create an abstraction of two printers behind the scene.

Please let me know if my understanding of your question was not correct or you need other clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement it in the described way, it usually works only with two different MFP's as the majority of TWAIN drivers do not support two different USB devicves at the same time.